# MDS - how to ensure that all fields contain a value?

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

we're using MDS to insert some records but sometimes we have users that insert empty values by mistake which results in some issues. Since we want to verify and validate all fields to ensure that none of them are null we have tried to look at the Business Rules that can be created within MDS. However, it seems that these will only validate the data if we apply the business rules when checking the data or via a stored procedure.

Is there any method or business rule in MDS which does not allow the users from inserting blank values and discards any rows that do not meet this criteria?